# Remove Duplicate Row while choosing smallest ID in 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following 2d Array:

```
ID  Site  Place
1.0 222.23 333.23
2.0 222.0  311.11
3.0 22.23  111.2
0.0 222.23 333.23
4.0 22.23  121.1
1.0 222.23 333.23
5.0 222.23 333.23
```

I want to remove any rows which has the **same Site and Place** and choose the smallest ID. For my given 2d array, the output should be:

```
 ID  Site  Place
2.0 222.0  311.11
3.0 22.23  111.2
0.0 222.23 333.23
4.0 22.23  121.1
```

I have tried loop to do this but the time it is taking is too long. I have also created another approach (see code below) but deletes exact copies only. A code snippet with simple explanation would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[]args){
        Double[][] loc_t = {
                {1.0,222.23,333.23},
                {2.0, 222.00, 311.11},
                {3.0, 22.23, 111.2},
                {0.0, 222.23, 333.23},
                {4.0, 22.23, 121.1},
                {1.0, 222.23, 333.23},
                {5.0, 222.23, 333.23},
                
 };
        System.out.println("ID Site  Place");
        Arrays.stream(loc_t)
              .map(Arrays::asList)
              .distinct()
              .forEach(row -> System.out.printf("%-3s%-7s%s\n", row.get(0), row.get(1), row.get(2)));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true distinct will only ensure the values are unique so you will not be able to remove duplicate items.

The following collects the items and counts the number 'filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1)' ensures only items with a count of one will be allowed in the stream output for collection.

```
        Arrays.stream(loc_t)
            .map(Arrays::asList)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1)
            .map(e -> e.getKey())
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .forEach(row -> System.out.printf("%s, %s, %s\n", row.get(0), row.get(1), row.get(2)));
```

Comment: If you want to gain an insight try '.filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1)'

Comment: Thanks @MarkAddison Wanted to know what is .collect doing as i have not really come across it before - java newbie.

Comment: If you remove the last line forEach - you can assign to a List<List<Double>>

Comment: if you add {5.0, 222.23, 333.23} to the input, the code incorrectly outputs `5.0, 222.23, 333.23` as well

Comment: the identiy is the complete row so 5.0 is distinct from 1.0

Comment: but then the answer (your code) does not provide the smallest ID for the same rows and columns eg. it should still only print `0.0 222.23 333.23` when you add `5.0, 222.23, 333.23`. any way to modify the code to fit criteria?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225089/discussion-between-markaddison-and-utso-roy).